# Why create the window does not respond?

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, winapi

When i create the window named'A' by CreateWindow function,the window 'A' become not responding,but can draw it before it does not respond.

When i click the 'Sign In' button

[image: Sign In]

```
unsigned __stdcall ThreadFunc(void *lParam) {
    pMsgHead pmsgHead = new MsgHead;
    while (RecvMsg(ConnectSocket,pmsgHead,sizeof(MsgHead))) {
        switch (pmsgHead->dwCmd) {
        case WM_SIGN_IN:
            g_hMain=CreateWindow(szMainClass, L"A", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                200, 200, 250, 500, 0, 0, hInst, nullptr);
            ShowWindow(g_hMain, SW_SHOW);
            UpdateWindow(g_hMain);
            break;
        case WM_BROADCAST:
            //DrawText()
            break;
        }
    }
    _endthreadex(0);
    return 0;
}
```

But when i click the 'Sign Up' button,it will work.

[image: Sign Up]

```
        case IDB_SIGN_UP:
            g_hSignUp = CreateWindow(szSignUpClass, L"Sign Up", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                800, 200, 300, 300, 0, 0, hInst, nullptr);
            ShowWindow(g_hSignUp, SW_SHOW);
            UpdateWindow(g_hSignUp);
            break;
        case IDB_SIGN_IN:
        {
            TCHAR uname[20], psd[20];
            GetWindowText(g_hSignInuname, uname, 20);
            GetWindowText(g_hSignInpsd, psd, 20);
            pMsgHead pmsgHead = new MsgHead;
            pmsgHead->dwCmd = WM_SIGN_IN;
            wcscpy_s(pmsgHead->tszbuf, uname);
            wcscat_s(pmsgHead->tszbuf, L",");
            wcscat_s(pmsgHead->tszbuf, psd);
            SendMsg(ConnectSocket, pmsgHead, sizeof(MsgHead));
            break;
        }
```

I just use while loop in GetMessage function in Main thread and RecvMsg in the above,I use the single-step debug the program, one thread will wait in

```
while(RecvMsg())
```

the Main thread will run the 'break' in

```
case IDB_SIGN_IN:
```

then return 0,if I still use single-step debug,it will tips not loaded 'wuser32.pdb'

Comment: Are you creating that window from another thread (not _main_ one)? You can't...

Comment: @Adriano: There is no such thing as a *main* thread.

Comment: @IInspectable let's call it _UI_ thread if you prefer or - better - thread where hInst has been created. In general UI is single threaded so _main_ thread is kind of _simplification_.

Comment: @Adriano: Uhm... *"thread where hInst has been created"* doesn't make any sense. hInst is a pointer to the beginning of the module that was used to create the process. It is a result of the OS loader; no thread has been created at that point. GUIs are also not strictly single threaded. A window **hierarchy** on the other hand, is best owned by a single thread.

Comment: @IInspectable GetModuleHandle() (equivalent to hInstance in WinMain for executables) will return a pseudo-handle. pseudo-handle means it's a constant (resolved, when needed, per thread, not per process). _"thread where hInst has been created"_: exactly what I wrote, to be a valid handle it must be handle returned by GetModuleHandle(NULL) or WinMain's hInstance if in _main_ thread (please remember handles are formally valid per thread). A window hierarchy is not _best_ owned in a single thread. It _has_ to be owned in a single thread (but different hierarchies may exist in different threads).

Comment: @IInspectable I guess Adriano means the first thread created in the process, which is invariably the one which creates the windows. The UI thread is more explicit, but that's what is meant when people say the main thread.

Comment: @Adriano: So much wrong, it boggles the mind... The `hInst` parameter passed to `WinMain` is not a pseudo handle. It's not even a handle at all. It's the **address** to the beginning of the module used to create the process. It won't get resolved, and is thread invariant. It exists already before a single thread is created. There's also no technical requirement for a window hierarchy to be owned by a single thread. Read [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx) for some education.

Comment: @IInspectable IMO you take it too _easy_. Let me explain: what an HINSTANCE is it's not something you can assume. It's an _opaque_ type. It may be an address, an entry point in a lookup table, a constant with some special meaning. GetModuleHandle(NULL) _may_ return a constant (by specs). GetModuleHandle(NULL) and hInstance are equivalent (for an exe, by specs again). Its value is per thread (by specs, again).

Comment: To summarize: both _handles_ are equivalent. They're handles, not addresses (it means you cannot _assume_ they're addresses). GetModuleHandle() may return a pseudo-handle and it's valid per thread. All from specs. Given these then also for hInstance you _should not_ assume it's valid per process (note I said _should_, it _may_ work but you're relying on an implementation detail).

Comment: @Adriano: I'm not assuming anything. [HINSTANCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx): *"A handle to an instance. **This is the base address of the module in memory**."* I'm relying on documentation. You're relying on uninformed opinion.

Comment: Let me explain further: GetModuleHandle(NULL) _may_ return NULL. hInstance _may_ have a value but also NULL (they don't _say_ it's invalid).

Comment: @IInspectable let me recall you **we're in 32/64 bit world, not 16 bit**. Each executable has its own address space...that's why it has to be an _opaque_ type and you cannot make assumptions about its exact value (it may even be NULL, always). From same source you cited: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/05/590749.aspx

Comment: And about window handles: they can be shared (still assuming they're _handles_, not _addresses_) across threads but you need both threads (_main_ one and the other) support this if you want to interoperate. As David wrote in his answer (my bad I can't explain myself better) you'll get messages filtered _by thread_ then GetMessage() in main thread (as OP is doing) won't ever get its messages.

Comment: In short: no, you cannot _safely_ mix controls created in different threads in the same window (it doesn't mean you can't do it in a very controlled scenario and if you **deeply know** what you're doing). You may have windows created in different thread within same application but each thread needs its message pump...

Comment: @Adriano: Could you make up your mind? First you say, that it's impossible to spawn a window hierarchy across threads, and now you turn around and say it isn't. So what is it? As for pointers: A pointer is valid in the address space it was retrieved. That doesn't make it an opaque data type. It's a pointer. Period. Since an HINSTANCE **is** a pointer (as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)), the same rules apply. Nowhere does this imply any sort of thread affinity. Now would you please stop confusing others, or provide facts to back your myths.

Comment: It's an HANDLE. Is it right? An handle is an opaque type. Do you want to argue about this? Can you assume it's a pointer? No, please (for your own sake do not do it, unless you think < 32 is a valid pointer, you may dereference NULL or it's somehow unique). Is a pointer valid across processes? No, right? Is then that HINSTANCE valid across processes? No (simple syllogism).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75915/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-adriano-repetti).

Comment: By case an HINSTANCE may be 0x400 (often) but ALSO NULL is a valid value (from MSDN, again see GetModuleHandle). Just do not ASSUME anything about that.

Comment: @Adriano: Final comment: **Everything** you said is wrong. That simple. A `HINSTANCE` is **not** a `HANDLE`. It is a pointer, as **documented**. Even if it were a `HANDLE`, it'd still be valid across all threads in the same process. Since there is no `DuplicateHandle` API call that takes thread handles, this should come as no surprise. You are making up facts that aren't. And this time around, please don't try to correct what's already correct. You've failed time upon time. Keep some dignity and move on. This apparently isn't your home territory.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't know your definition of *dignity* (are you always so mean?) but I think it's my *duty* to explain my opinion (if I think I am right).  If I was wrong then it's best chance to learn something new. I see this topic is going to be too long to be discussed in comments. Later I will post a question,  feel free to contribute with your own answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the window in a thread. Which means the window has affinity with that thread. Messages are sent to that threads message queue. You don't have a message loop in the thread so nothing can respond to the messages.

The fix is to create all your windows in the main thread. You should send a message to the main window that asks for your other window to be created. That way you will ensure that all your windows are created by the main UI thread.